# Displaying elaborated video frame by a toch model in Flask

Tags: flask, pytorch, sqlalchemy, frontend, backend

I am developing a Flask Web App in which user select a video from os, this video is loaded in SQLAlchemy and then the application must display it.
Aim of the app is to predict BPM from video, trough a Pytorch model.
Each frame must pass trough a custom pipeline and my custom model, for each frame, must do prediction.
Now, I want that displayed video is like the original but at each frame must be box around the face and the predicted above the bounding box.
I tried different solutions but I am completely stuck and I don't have experience in front-end.

```
    def index():
    last_video = Video.query.order_by(Video.id.desc()).first()
    return last_video.id if last_video else None


class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = None

    def __del__(self):
        if self.video:
            self.video.release()

    def get_video_from_db(self):
        video_data = Video.query.get(index())
        if video_data:
            self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_data.path)
            return self.video

    def get_frame(self):
        if self.video:
            _, image = self.video.read()
            _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
            return jpeg.tobytes()
        else:
            return b'', None

def gen(camera):
    frame_count = 0
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        frame_count += 1
        if frame_count % 40 == 0:
            faces = face_detector(frame, 1)
            if faces:
                face = faces[0]
                print("Faccia trovata")
                landmarks = landmark_predictor(frame, face.rect)
                face_region = extract_face_region(frame, landmarks)
                print("Regione viso estratta")
                if face_region is not None:
                    img = extract_features(face_region, Pl, 30, Fl, Fh)
                    print("Regione viso estratta")
                    with torch.no_grad():
                        output = model_load(img)

                    predicted_value = output.item()
                    pred_denorm = denormalize(predicted_value, max_mean_hr, min_mean_hr)
                    annotated_frame = draw_annotations(frame.copy(), face, pred_denorm)

                    yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +
                           cv2.imencode('.jpg', annotated_frame)[1].tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')
            else:
                frame_count += 1
        else:
            frame_count += 1


@views.route('/get_video', methods=['GET'])
def get_video():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

This is the button in html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('views.get_video') }}" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="buttons-container">
            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <button type="submit" class="upload-btn btn btn-primary">Upload last video</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can someone help to fix the code in order to display video with annotated frames?
Thanks.